# How do I make my background-image fit the entire screen CSS

Tags: css

CSS:

```
    body{
      background-image:url("img-address");
    }
```

I want the image not to repeat itself multiple times, but to span the entire screen. I don't want to use a normal image I want to use `background-image`.

Comment: use background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: try using `background-repeat: no-repeat` and have a look at the unit `vh` for the spanning the whole screen

Comment: This worked for me:
background: url(image.jpeg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;

Answer (score 7):

you can use `background-size`:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
body {
  background-size: 100% 100% ;
}
```

or

```
body {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to make it fit:

```
background-size:cover; Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

background-size:contain; Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible
```

So it does not repeat: `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-repeat: none` and `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `background-size: cover;` as described in this article: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

It will make the image stretch to fill the available space and scale accordingly to the size of its container.

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: It works, but at first, I forgot to add a semicolon. This helps!